# Why do my variables are successful changed in a StatelessWidget, even tho I get a warning

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the warning:

> This class (or a class which this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields are not final: MyWidget.myVar

The console tells me that the variable must be final. I suspect that I should change my widget to a stateful if I want to change variables, but to me it doesn't makes sense, as the code works as intended. When I change my variable I don't want to change anything on the screen, I just want to use it later.

What I'm doing is wrong? If not, how can I disable this warning?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyWidget(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  String myVar;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          MaterialButton(
            child: Text('Click me do change variable'),
            onPressed: () {
              myVar = 'Clicked!';
            },
          ),
          MaterialButton(
            child: Text('Click me to print the variable'),
            onPressed: () {
              print(myVar);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is correct and it doesn't really matter since you are not outputting anything on screen. However the best practise is to change it to a Stateful Widget.

It doesn't really affect it in a negative way.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the warning because all fields in a class extending StatelessWidget should be final.

Fix the warning by adding the `final` keyword before the `type` declaration like below:

`final String myVar;`

From the documentations.

> StatelessWidget class. A widget that does not require mutable state.

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html

I hope this answers your question

Comment: Yeah I can make it final, or make the widget a StatefulWidget, but why my code works? The logic behind my code is that I need to change the variable, and don't need to change or rebuild the screen once I did it. Is the logic correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct. Since you don't need the changed variable to be displayed, your logic is correct. If you need the changed variable to be displayed on the screen, you would have to use a stateful widget and call ```setstate``` method. @LucasMaffazioli

Answer (score 0):

The point of changing variable's value in a stateful widget is that you can call

```
setState(() {
  myVar = 'clicked';
});
```

Which would rebuild the UI, changing a Text widget's content.

Try adding a Text(myVar) to your column, in a stateless widget it wouldn't change on a press of a button. But in a stateful widget it will change.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. My point is that I need to change the variable and not change the screen. The code works, but gives me a warning. Is my logic correct or wrong? Can I disable the warning if correct?

Comment: I would still suggest using stateful widget but without setState function

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the state of a variable in a Widget, you need to use a StetefullWidget.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String myInitialVar;

  const MyWidget({Key key, this.myInitialVar}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyWidgetState(myInitialVar);

}

class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  String myVar;

  MyWidgetState(this.myVar);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          MaterialButton(
            child: Text('Click me do change variable'),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                myVar = 'Clicked!';
              });
            },
          ),
          MaterialButton(
            child: Text('Click me to print the variable'),
            onPressed: () {
              print(myVar);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```